# Error Message: why i am getting "None" although i have add get() at views.py in Django ??? Can anyone help me

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

This is my Views.py file and in this file I am trying to get the value from HTML

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import kitchenData
from django.http import HttpResponse


def kitchen(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        table_num = request.POST.get('table_num')
        full_name = request.POST.get('full_name')
        qty = request.POST.get('qty')
        drink_name = request.POST.get('drinks_name')
        drink_qty = request.POST.get('drinks_qty')
        message = request.POST.get('message')
        price = request.POST.get('price')
        status = request.POST.get('status')
        print(table_num,full_name,qty,drink_name,drink_qty,message,price,status)
        return render(request, 'kitchen/kitchen_order.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'kitchen/kitchen_order.html')
```

HTML Photo
[image: HTML Photo]
[image: HTML Photo]

```
[![i have attached the output][1]][1]  

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4pYy.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't have `input` value in your html. So all the `values` are `None`.

Change your `html` from

```
<tr>
   <td>Full Name: </td>
   <td name="full_name">Shiva Giri<td>
</tr>
```

To

```
    <tr>
       <td>Full Name: </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="full_name" value="Shiva Giri"><td>
    </tr>
```

And so on for all other `remaining` values.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you want to know why you get `None` when you use the `get()` method on a dictionary/request.

This is because the requested key does not exist and you did not specify any default value for the `get()` that should be used if the key does not exist. In that case `None` is returned.

[This is also explained in detail in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11041421/13439686)

Answer (score 0):

`request.POST.get()` gets values from `<input>` and `<select>` tags not from table tags.

You can try with hidden inputs like this: `<input type="hidden" id="table_num" name="table_num" value="DC 8">`

You will need to do this for all the information you want to send into the backend. Do not forget to add `id=""` and `name=""` to all inputs/select tags